# How to setup off chain database for hyper ledger fabric?

Tags: database, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm facing difficulty to setup off chain database....is off chain database setup is same as normal database setup?

I read the documentation but i can't find anything. It tell us to setup couchDB. But I also not know that how to setup couchDB for off chain database

Please lemme know.if anyone have the answers about off chain database

Answer (score 1):

An off-chain database is different from the world state database - which can be CouchDB or LevelDB - used internally within each peer to store the current ledger state.

An off-chain database refers to any data store used to hold a replica of all or part of the ledger (or transaction) data. This is usually done to keep the data in a format or location where it can be more efficiently searched. The data store you use and the format in which you store the data is entirely dependent on the requirements of your application.

Fabric's [off_chain_data sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/off_chain_data) describes a mechanism for extracting transactions and the modifications they have made to ledger state. It is up to you to choose how you then store that data.